# how to solve this problem on complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

in a probelm set I found $(x + \sqrt2j)(x − \sqrt2ij) =(x^2 + 2x + 2)$ where $j=√i$

but i can't understand  how this happened. 
I have done this $(x + \sqrt2j)(x − \sqrt2ij)=x^2-2i^2+x\sqrt2j(1-i)=x^2-2+x\sqrt2j(1-i)$

then what will happen please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, note that $-2i^2 = 2$, not $-2$.  Second, we do in fact have
$$
\sqrt{2}\,j(1 - i) = 2
$$
so your result makes sense.  That is, with careful analysis, we find that
$$
x^2-2i^2+x\sqrt2j(1-i) = x^2 + 2x + 2
$$
In fact, instead of using "$j$", note that
$$
\sqrt{i} = [\cos(\pi/2) + i\sin(\pi/2)]^{1/2} = \cos(\pi/4) + i\sin(\pi/4) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1 + i)
$$